# Closed Lid & External Monitor

Tags: unity, gnome, laptop, 14.10, external-monitor

I would like to work on a monitor connected to my laptop with closed lid.

I can change laptop's behavior to "Do nothing" when the lid is closed and everything works perfectly (just my account log out while closing lid).

But this behavior is not desired. I want the laptop to suspend after lid is closed. Only when an external monitor is connected, I don't want it to suspend. I tried to google it, but I really was not succesful. I saw an useful option in gnome-tweak-tool (which should do exactly what I want), but it unfortunately does not affect anything.

I am running Ubuntu 14.10 and I connect the monitor via VGA.

Answer (score 1):

If you upgrade to Ubuntu 15.04, this behavior would be by default.

See */etc/systemd/logind.conf*:

```
#HandleLidSwitch=suspend
#HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
```